# A semi-rectangle frame

Tags: framed

I was wondering how it is possible to enclose a block of text or a word in a semi-rectangle frame. For clarity, I attach a picture in which a word: *solution*'s frames are the subject of the question.
[image: border]

Comment: Have a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility without too fancy packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{3cm}>{\centering}X}
\cline{1-1}
\emph{Solution}: & $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^6\pi\,f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. You could wrap this into an environment for easier use: `\newenvironment{solution}[1][Solution]{\tabularx{\linewidth}{|p{3cm}>{\centering}X}\cline{1-1}
  \textit{#1}:&}{\endtabularx}` and then `\begin{solution}
     $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^6\pi\,f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y$
  \end{solution}`

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for pointing this out! I completely agree. The question is if my proposal is what the OP is looking for.